# Conditional pdf of a product of two uniform independent variables

Tags: conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Let A ~ U(0,1) and B ~ U(0,1) be independent uniform random variables and T = AB, the product of A and B. Find the conditional pdf f(t| B = 2/3) and the joint pdf of A and T f(a,t).

Started by finding the density of T to be -ln(t) for t (0,1]. Please help in finding the conditional pdf.

Comment: Hint: when $B=2/3$, $T=AB=(2/3)A$ which takes on values in $(0,2/3)$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Could I use this to multiply the two pdf's together? f(t| B = 2/3) = f(b,t)/f_B(b) where f(b,t) = f_B(b) * f_T(t) = 1*2/3 = 2/3?

Comment: $B$ and $T$ are not independent random variables (for example, the value of $T$ is always smaller than the value of $B$) and so you can’t just multiply their pdfs to arrive at the joint pdf.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the [tag:self-study]
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).